# multiple commands in sed with xargs input

Tags: linux, sed, xargs

I've a file `./123bar/foo.txt` which has:

```
pro := text
ver := 1.0
rev := 2
```

and two env variables:

```
var =2.1
var2=3
```

I want to replace all `ver` with `$var` and `rev` with `$var2`. Expected output:

```
pro := text
ver := 2.1
rev := 3
```

I'm trying below to first find all the files with `find` and `grep` and then pass it to `sed` to achieve the result.
Below is the command I'm running:

```
find . -name 'foo.txt' | grep -P "\/[0-9]{3}bar" | xargs -I{} sed -E "s/:= *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ *$/:= $var/g" -E "s/:= [0-9]+ *$/:= $var2/g" {}
```

it's not working and giving me error:

```
sed: can't read s/:= [0-9]+ *$/:= 3/g: No such file or directory
pro := text
ver := 2.1
rev := 45
```

How do I fix it? A neater/simpler solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option for using multiple expressions with sed is `-e`, not `-E`:

```
sed -e "s/:= *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ *$/:= $var/g" -e "s/:= [0-9]+ *$/:= $var2/g"
```

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options) (assuming GNU given the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag):

> '-e SCRIPT'
>   '--expression=SCRIPT'
>        Add the commands in SCRIPT to the set of commands to be run while
>        processing the input.

`-E` is for using extended regular expressions.

Comment: got it but the above command not working. adding -E in the beginning worked though: `sed -E -e "s/:= *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ *$/:= $var/g" -e "s/:= [0-9]+ *$/:= $var2/g"`. thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: @helix ah, I see, you're using `+`, which does need `-E`. I didn't notice that at first. If you use `\+` instead, though, you won't need the `-E`.